# Server-side Rendering React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Всем привет. Возник вопрос по серверному рендеру стэка из REACT и REDUX.

Загружаю данные так:

```
/Component.jsx
...
static initialAction() { 
  return dispatch => { 
     axios.post('url')
     .then(res => res.data)
     .then(data=>dispatch({type: 'SET_TEST', test: data}))
     .catch(e=>console.log(e)); 
  }
}
...
```

На сервере это выглядит так

```
server.js
...
const promises = routes.reduce((acc, route) => { 
  if (matchPath(req.url, route) && route.component && route.component.initialAction){
 acc.push(Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(route.component.initialAction()))); 
  } 
  return acc; 
}, []);
Promise.all(promises).then(()=>{
//Вся морока с рендером
});
...
```

route.component.initialAction() - это и есть функция выше

Все работает так как нужно, но допустим мне нужно отрендерить динамическую страницу. Как передать параметр в эту статическую функцию? Параметр из строки естественно.
Сделать допустим такой запрос:

Как вариант парсить `req.url`, но будет ли это правильным решением ?